# Difficulty using a VPN in Kali Linux

Tags: vpn, kali-linux, openvpn

I am attempting to connect my machine running Kali Linux rolling addition to a VPN (using OpenVPN connection). I created a free account [here](https://www.securitykiss.com/), downloaded the necessary configuration files, and then added the VPN in the Kali Network Manager. When I attempt to connect to this VPN, it says I am connected. However, when I go to check my IP/Geo location, it has not changed. Any help would be appreciated!

> Updated Information!

Routing Tables without VPN:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

Routing Tables with VPN:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
10.12.0.14      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 tun0
23.19.26.250    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

Output of OpenVPN Files (named update-resolv-conf):

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
# Parses DHCP options from openvpn to update resolv.conf
# To use set as 'up' and 'down' script in your openvpn *.conf:
# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
#
# Used snippets of resolvconf script by Thomas Hood and Chris Hanson.
# Licensed under the GNU GPL.  See /usr/share/common-licenses/GPL. 
# 
# Example envs set from openvpn:
#
#     foreign_option_1='dhcp-option DNS 193.43.27.132'
#     foreign_option_2='dhcp-option DNS 193.43.27.133'
#     foreign_option_3='dhcp-option DOMAIN be.bnc.ch'
#

[ -x /sbin/resolvconf ] || exit 0
[ "$script_type" ] || exit 0
[ "$dev" ] || exit 0

split_into_parts()
{
    part1="$1"
    part2="$2"
    part3="$3"
}

case "$script_type" in
  up)
    NMSRVRS=""
    SRCHS=""
    for optionvarname in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do
        option="${!optionvarname}"
        echo "$option"
        split_into_parts $option
        if [ "$part1" = "dhcp-option" ] ; then
            if [ "$part2" = "DNS" ] ; then
                NMSRVRS="${NMSRVRS:+$NMSRVRS }$part3"
            elif [ "$part2" = "DOMAIN" ] ; then
                SRCHS="${SRCHS:+$SRCHS }$part3"
            fi 
        fi
    done
    R=""
    [ "$SRCHS" ] && R="search $SRCHS
 "
    for NS in $NMSRVRS ; do
        R="${R}nameserver $NS
"
    done
    echo -n "$R" | /sbin/resolvconf -a "${dev}.openvpn"
    ;;
  down)
    /sbin/resolvconf -d "${dev}.openvpn"
    ;;
esac
```

After running suggested command:

```
root@kali:/etc/openvpn# openvpn --config config.ovpn
Sat Mar  5 14:45:15 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL   (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan 21 2016
Sat Mar  5 14:45:15 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016, LZO 2.08
Sat Mar  5 14:45:15 2016 WARNING: file 'client.key' is group or others  accessible
Sat Mar  5 14:45:15 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sat Mar  5 14:45:15 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]23.19.26.250:5353
Sat Mar  5 14:45:16 2016 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with     [AF_INET]23.19.26.250:5353
Sat Mar  5 14:45:18 2016 TUN/TAP device tun2 opened
Sat Mar  5 14:45:18 2016 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0,     tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sat Mar  5 14:45:18 2016 /sbin/ip link set dev tun2 up mtu 1500
Sat Mar  5 14:45:18 2016 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun2 local 10.13.0.98 peer     10.13.0.97
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Mar  5 14:45:23 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external  program exited with error status: 2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Mar  5 14:45:23 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external    program exited with error status: 2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Mar  5 14:45:23 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external     program exited with error status: 2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Mar  5 14:45:23 2016 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external   program exited with error status: 2
Sat Mar  5 14:45:23 2016 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Comment: This appears to be a linux question, not a security question. Migrating.

Comment: In order to diagnose this, you will have to provide your routing tables both on and off the OpenVPN, and the output of the OpenVPN files, located in `/etc/openvpn` and/or `/var/log`.  As for `geoip location`, I hope you mean by that that you went to this site,  `geoiptool.com`, is this right?

Comment: I added the information you mentioned. And yes, that was one of the geo-location tools I used. @MariusMatutiae

Comment: Your routing table is surely wrong.  can you please post your conf file, which should be located in `/etc/openvpn`?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae What do you mean my routing table is wrong? I posted both word for word as they showed in my terminal. Also when I go to /etc/openvpn there is only a update-resolv-conf file which is what I posted.

Comment: I mean it is incorrectly setup, I have no doubt you have reproduced the table correctly.  Also: you must have somewhere a file specifying the options of the OpenVPN, stating which server to connect to, the type of virtual interface, the compression (if any) and so on. I need to see that in order to understand why your routing table is not correctly setup.

Comment: Never mind, pls read my answer.

Comment: Good, you are connected, that's it.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae So in the future when I want to run this vpn, do I have to run the terminal command `openvpn --config config.ovpn` every time? And also, should the VPN show up in the network manager GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have registered for the same service myself, and it works just fine.Your `config` file should look like this,

```
remote 23.19.26.250
port 5353
client
dev tun
pull
resolv-retry infinite
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
persist-key
ns-cert-type server
persist-tun
comp-lzo
nobind
mute-replay-warnings
route-delay 5
keepalive 5 28
```

Make sure yours is identical to mine. Then issue these commands:

```
 apt-get install openvpn
 openvpn --config config.ovpn
```

where the second command must be given in the directory where you have the files `ca.crt, client.crt, client.key, config.ovpn`.

Now open a new terminal and issue this command:

```
 wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -
```

Its output should be 23.19.26.150

Comment: The problem is, I am unable to find my Config file. It is not located in the '/etc/openvpn/' directory where it should be. Is it simply hidden or is this a problem with the actual installation?

Comment: @Steve Do what follows: `find / -name 'security-kiss*'`. Otherwise you may download it again from the site.

Comment: I get `find: ‘/run/user/133/gvfs’: Permission denied`

Comment: @Steve That's not important, carry on.

Comment: I updated my question with the output after running the second terminal command you suggested.

Comment: @Steve  I never use the Network Manager,so I do not know whether it is broken or not. I always use the CLI. And no, it should not show up in its GUI. The way  to find out whether you are using the VPN or not is the last command I posted. BTW, Kali requires that you know the CLI reasonably well, even though many programs have GUIs.

Comment: I appreciate all your help